# How to use Word2Vec CBOW in statistical algorithm?

Tags: nlp, logistic-regression, word2vec

I have seen a few examples of using CBOW in neural network models (although I did not understand them).

I know that Word2Vec is not similar to BOW or TFIDF, as there is no single value for CBOW and all examples I saw were used neural networks.

I have 2 questions:

1: Can we convert the vector to a single value and put it in a dataframe so we can use it in logistic regression model?

2: Is there any simple code for CBOW usage with logistic regression?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. CBOW or SkipGram (the 2 word2vec models) both give a vector embedding for each word. What do you mean "convert the vector to a single value"?

Answer (score 0):

If you want one value per word rather than a vector, you could run the CBOW algorithm (or skipgram, the other w2v model) with an embedding side of 1. But it is unlikely to work well since the semantic meaning of a word can't easily be reduced a single value.

That said, you can feed vector inputs into logistic regression though, e.g. single word embeddings or several concatenated together.

Comment: How to feed it into logistic regression? can you share a simple example?